# Исчезает изображение на сайте после CSS эффекта (только на одной странице)

Tags: html, css

На [сайте](http://doma-nk.ru/stroitelstvo-bani-iz-brusa-pod-klyuch-v-novokuzneczke.html#projects) если кликнуть по проекту в каталоге и затем закрыть открывшееся модальное окно, картинка проекта пропадает (сдвигается с места, хотя не должна). Возвращается только если на ней подержать мышку.

Пропадает задний план при открытии какого либо оконной страницы.
Ну и лагает при прокрутке и переходах.

Как исправить?

Comment: добавьте пример кода...  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @And перенесите этот комментарий в тело вопроса (нажмите кнопку ***править***)

Comment: @Air, Покажите код который отрабатывает по кнопке `Подробнее`.

Comment: @And, не понял вопроса... Вопрос видать адресован не мне а bars96

Comment: @Air, извеняюсь да это `bars96` - я нашел Вашу проблему, но не знаю, как у вас устроено все. Проблема в `maskp` элементе, когда его удаляем картинка возвращается, а также решается убиранием `overflow`. Проблема в коде, которого вы не предоставили.

Comment: @And, я вопрос не задавал, адресу коммент правильно))

Comment: @Air, само подставилось =)

Comment: владельцу вопроса  адресовать не надо, он его и так увидит)))  коммент в смысле...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то не так с кнопкой button.openbox, проблема случается только при нажатии на нее.
Можно, например, сделать ее не `button`, а `div`.
Ну и стили можно дописать для .grid .thumbnail .openbox, что бы нормально отображался

```
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 104px;
width: 150px;
```

Comment: Спасибо, поменял кнопку на тег `span` и прописал ей `display: inline-block;`. Проблема решена